# Trying to figure out how to hide my PHPSESSID to prevent session stealing

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to hide my PHPSESSID by using .htaccess I know that it's something to do with HTTPONLY. I currently have `php_flag session.cookie_httponly 1` in my .htaccess file but it is not working and I can still simply write something like `<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>` and retrieve the id. Can **anyone** help?

Comment: I'm unsure why you're trying to hide the session ID. What are you worried about?

Comment: someone can use XSS in order to steal the session id then they would be able to use that to log in as me

Comment: Does your setup _allow_ you to make such settings in .htaccess? // You can also call `session_set_cookie_params` in your script before you start the session.

Comment: Make sure any old "PHPSESSID" cookie is deleted before checking that the cookie is visible in JavaScript. It will be recreated with the correct flag as long as the browser and php configuration supports the flag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php
(The 'true' flag tells the system to delete old session information)

to regenerate the session ID. That way, if someone steal the session, it will most likely of already expired by the time they try and use it.

Although, the best option is to prevent any chance of anyone stealing the session ID in the first place.

Filter all inputs from the user, POST data, GET data, COOKIES. All user input!

Additionally, look in to these

```
//Increase session security
ini_set( 'session.cookie_httponly', '1' ); //Prevents potential XSS
ini_set( 'session.use_only_cookies', '1' ); //Don't use GET for session ID
ini_set( 'session.cookie_secure', '1' ); //SSL only
define('COOKIE_HTTPONLY', TRUE); //Prevents potential XSS
define('COOKIE_SSL', TRUE); //SSL only on cookies
```